# list in python behaviour

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have a list my_list created as `mylist = [[]]*5`

now I want to add an integer say 4 to the third list in my_list

`my_list[2].append(4)`

When I print out my_list i see that every list in my_list has the integer 4 added to it.

`>>> my_list = [[]]*5`

`>>> my_list[2].append(4)`

`>>> my_list`

`[[4], [4], [4], [4], [4]]`

is there a way to just have 4 added to the 3rd list?

expected: `[[],[],[4],[],[]]`

actual: `[[4],[4],[4],[4],[4]]`

Answer (score 1):

TL,DR:

```
mylist = [list() for i in xrange(5)]
```

---

When python meets `mylist = [[]]*5`, it will create **one** entity list in your memory, and append 5 references of this only one list to mylist.

It is equal to this:

```
single_list = []
mylist = [single_list, single_list, single_list, single_list, single_list]
```

So, if you append 4 to the third list, `4` is now in the single_list, and since all of the 5 references is to the same `single_list`, it looks like all of the 5 lists contains `4`.

Answer (score 0):

figured out the answer.

`my_list = [[] for i in xrange(5)]`

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Well my understanding of what is going on is that when you run `[[]]` it just creates multiple references to one initialized list. I believe **`[[] for i in range(5)]`** is what you are looking for; it initializes different lists inside the parent list. Hope this helps!